# Node: Traversing directories in a recursion

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback, traversal

I'm pretty new to Node...I need to hammer Node's async behavior and callback structure into my mind. Here where I struggle right now:

```
   // REQUIRE --------------------------------------------------------------------
   fs      = require('fs');
   path    = require('path');

   // FUNCTION readAllDirs -------------------------------------------------------
   function readAllDirs(dir, result) {
      if (!result) {
            result = function() {};
      };

      fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {
            if(err) { return result(err) };

            list.forEach(function(file) {
                    var fullpath = path.resolve(dir, file);

                    fs.stat(fullpath, function(err, stat) {
                            if(err) { return result(err) };

                            if(stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                                    readAllDirs(fullpath);
                                    //console.log('In: ' + fullpath);
                                    result(null, fullpath);
                            }
                    });
            });
      });
   }

   // MAIN -----------------------------------------------------------------------
   readAllDirs('/somedir', function(err, dirs) {
            console.log(dirs);
   });
```

I try to traverse a tree of directories. In principle the function is working nice...as long I do not callback but print the directory names on the console. All folders and sub-folders come up as expected. BUT when I do callbacks the callback is not called for recursion deeper than first level.

Pleeeaaassee help! Thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks to Alnitak. 

Thinking about it the issue I quite clear now. The callback function (in the example above the function with console.log...) needs to be provided for every readAllDirs function call. I haven't done so inside the readAllDirs function itself. So, no callback function and no console.log... was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here, inside the `if (stat ...)` branch:

```
readAllDirs(fullpath);
```

You need to pass the supplied callback again back into the recursion:

```
readAllDirs(fullpath, result);
```

Comment: That did the job! Thank you so much!